# How to shim using statement?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, microsoft-fakes

I have a method similar to the following:

```
public List<EmployeeReports> MyMethod (int empId, DateTime startDate)
{
  using(SomeEntities se = new SomeEntities())
  {
   List<EmployeeReports> reports = se.EmployeeReports
   .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == empId
   && DateTime.Compare(x.DateEntered, startDate).ToList();
  }

 return reports;
}
```

This is an entity framework object to a database.

How can the using block be shimmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop using the ***new*** keyword in any code.
If this ***SomeEntities*** is of utmost necessity pass it to the constructor of the class (constructor Injection).
If ***SomeEntities*** needs to be overriden and assignment is no the prime requirement for creating the object of the class and ensure that ***SomeEntities*** are set before the function call  (Property Injection).

Comment: I'd say that goes a bit too far. There are objects that can be constructed safely. DI is very important, but the `new` keyword isn't evil. You might be right in this case, but not in every case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Magus.
    new keyword (with custom classes as against CLR classes) is the easiest way to figure out if one is adding dependencies and should start using DI.
I generally avoid using new with my classes. It has helped me a lot.

Comment: How are you creating class instances if you never use new?  I've updated the OP with additional info.  EF auto creates these classes and doesn't add an interface behind them.

Comment: Dependency Injection will do it for you. DI framework runs through algorithms and create necessary objects.

Comment: @ZiaullahKhan 's point refers to Unit testing.  Every object should have an Interface that reflects it.  If you have control of the code, create an Interface.  If not, Use the Builder-Model to wrap the object, and make an interface of that.  In that sense, nothing ever uses the New keyword within the class that uses it.  But the parent that instantiates your class may very well use the New keyword, then pass the dependency as a property into your constructor or method.  But this doesn't help with the Using statement, which is somewhat Required to be instantiated In-Line, and makes DI difficult

Answer (score 3):

I would abstract the `SomeEntities` class through an interface, That way you can inject an alternative implementation of the same interface in your tests.

Comment: Injection is very important in this case, because `SomeEntities` can only be called a dependency. The fact that the OP reached for shims is an example of a code smell working; an injectable dependency became obvious.